# How to access Order class property using property Orders in Customer in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public string CustomerLocation { get; set; }

    public Order[] Orders { get; set; }
}

[Table("Orders")]
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public Nullable<int> OrderId { get; set; }

    public string OrderName { get; set; }

    public Nullable<DateTime> OrderDate { get; set; }
}

public  class CustomerContext:DbContext
{
    public CustomerContext()
        :base("name=CustomerContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet <Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class OrderContext : DbContext
{
    public OrderContext()
        :base("name=OrderContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

I am not able set and get the `Order` properties using the order properties in `Customer` class I am able to get and set the data using the object of context class but not able to set or get the value of order class properties. Could somebody please suggest how to do this approach?

Comment: First of all, OrderId from Order shouldn't be nullable, because it is the primary key.

Comment: Order class should have a Customer property.

Comment: yes i had made changes accordingly .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, OrderId from Order shouldn't be nullable, because it is the primary key.
Order class should have a Customer property.

You can use only one context class where to have both properties

```
public DbSet <Customer> Customers { get; set; }
public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

Something like this:

```
public  class CustomerContext:DbContext
{
    public CustomerContext()
        :base("name=CustomerContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet <Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Try this for Order class:

```
[Table("Orders")]
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string OrderName { get; set; }

    public Nullable<DateTime> OrderDate { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Glad that it worked. You may accept this answer if it provides a solution.